# Django model not updating image field correctly (Raw content)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My model:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='pictures')
```

Update a single object:

```sh
>>> picture
>>> <ContentFile: Raw content>
>>> mymodel = MyModel.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
>>> mymodel.picture = picture
>>> mymodel.save()
>>> mymodel.picture
>>> <ImageFieldFile: pictures/fbdfe25b-b246-4f2d-9436-dca49aef88d7.png>
```

Good. Url result `/media/pictures/fbdfe25b-b246-4f2d-9436-dca49aef88d7.png`.

Update a single object with the `update()` method:

```sh
>>> picture
>>> <ContentFile: Raw content>
>>> MyModel.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk).update(picture=picture)
>>> mymodel = MyModel.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
>>> mymodel.picture
>>> <ImageFieldFile: Raw content>
```

Bad. Url result: `/media/Raw%20content`.

Comment: what does MyModel.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk) return

Comment: True. Thanks, add a line in my explanation

Comment: That is intended behaviour, `update` directly makes a SQL query to update potentially multiple instances so it does not save any files. If an instance is to be modified with an image one **must** use `save`

Comment: Thanks. I think I should not return True. Is confuse

Comment: @mcardozo hey, did you manage to resolve the issue. Having the same problem

Comment: I created issue in site DjangoProject https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32679